# shorten my code please

Tags: jquery, twitter

my code will be shown below but before you look and understand what I am trying to do, just know that I know that this will probably not work on twitter but I just want to try it out as this is mostly how I learn, by challenging myself to do things I know is not in my range then strive to beat it! So, the code is as below:

```
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
$('.Icon Icon--retweet').trigger('click')
$('.btn primary-btn retweet-action').trigger('click')
})
</script>
```

This is the code I have wrote to attempt to auto retweet a tweet, but, due to twitter tweet length restrictions, it does not fit. I have already subtracted the "enter-key button action I cannot think the name of at this time" so don't mention that. And I only need to shorten this by 2 so... Have fun!

Comment: look for alternatives of document ready $() will do fine

Comment: I'm assuming your trigger function doesn't work. That is what I could make off the title.

Comment: No, literally replace `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` with `$(function(){...})`

Comment: I see the problem is to the fire the function. In which case my answer wouldn't help I suppose.

Comment: If any of you were the one to flag or downrate, then please give me the curtesy of telling me why before you get me banned from ever asking question because I don't see how my question could offend you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you want to trigger the nested button

```
$('.Icon Icon--retweet > .btn primary-btn retweet-action').trigger('click');
```

If not, just set an id attribute by `id='mybutton'` to whichever element you want and use

```
$('#mybutton').trigger('click');
```